# Create JSX tree from flat Array with recursive function in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion, jsx

I really need your help to create a JSX tree from a flat array in react using recursive function.

For the moment only the items 1 to 6 are correctly displayed and the recursion is stopped after

[image: My falt array look like that]

[image: My aim is to create this JSX tree related to the level]

1) my flat JSON data is : (but it could have more than 1000 items)

```
const itemsData = [
{
  "Level": 1,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118027222233,
  "Name": "Name 1"
},
{
  "Level": 2,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118636886633,
  "Name": "Name 2"
},
{
  "Level": 3,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118637048333,
  "Name": "Name 3"
},
{
  "Level": 4,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118637035433,
  "Name": "Name 4"
},
{
  "Level": 4,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118841127933,
  "Name": "Name 5"
},
{
  "Level": 4,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118841156833,
  "Name": "Name 6"
},
{
  "Level": 3,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118637046733,
  "Name": "Name 9"
},
{
  "Level": 4,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118744514633,
  "Name": "Name 10"
},
{
  "Level": 5,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118637033033,
  "Name": "Name 11"
},
{
  "Level": 5,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118637031033,
  "Name": "Name 13"
},
{
  "Level": 2,
  "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
  "ID": 118636886633,
  "Name": "Name 19"
},
{
  "Level": 3,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118637048333,
  "Name": "Name 20"
},
{
  "Level": 3,
  "Type of activity": "task",
  "ID": 118637048333,
  "Name": "Name 21"
}]
```

2) My current recursive function looks like that :
But only Item 1 to 6 are correctly displayed.

```
const RecursiveFunction = ({currentItem, currentLevel}) => {

//LOOP  AS LONG AS CURRENTITEM < ITEMS DATA LENGTH 
while(currentItem < itemsData.length){

    //IF CONSOLODATED TASK CREATE CONTAINER
    if(itemsData[currentItem]["Type of activity"] === "Consolidated task"){


        //TEST IF CHILD RELATED TO LEVEL
        if(currentLevel < itemsData[currentItem].Level ){


            //LINE COUNTER
            currentItem++;

            //RETURN
            return (
                <div className="conso-container">
                    <div className="conso-title">
                        {itemsData[currentItem - 1].Name}
                    </div>
                    <RecursiveFunction currentItem={currentItem} currentLevel={itemsData[currentItem-1].Level} />
                </div>
            )
        }

    }else{

        //CURRENT TASK LIST ON A BLOCK
        let taskList = [];

        //WHILE IS A TASK
        while(currentItem < itemsData.length && itemsData[currentItem]["Type of activity"] !== "Consolidated task"){

            //LIST ALL THE TASK
            taskList.push(<div className="task-title">{itemsData[currentItem].Name}</div>)
            currentItem++;

        }

        // RETURN    
        return (
            <div className="task-container">
                {taskList}
            </div>
        )
    }
}}
```

3)My render is

```
class RoadMapItems extends React.Component {


render(){
    return( 
        <div className="tree">
            <RecursiveFunction currentItem={0} currentLevel={0} />
        </div>
    )
}}export default RoadMapItems;
```

Comment: And what is the actual question? :)

Comment: Actually nothing is working ... i linked two pictures to show you what my aim is. but i don't know if my strategy is the good one

Comment: @julienlaurent the problem is you are passing `items` again as a complete array which means the 1st time it gets 10 items passed & the 1st recursion you are again passing 10 items so it keeps looping infinitely

Comment: Since you have a flatList, why do you have a recursive function

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri how i can create my jsx tree related to the level number without recursive function ?

Comment: Is the array always ordered? It might help if you have a parentID field on the children, but if they are always ordered correctly, that could be done on the fly I suppose. @ShubhamKhatri is correct, with a flat representation, you shouldn't need recursion, if you convert your flat to nested (parentID would help) or if you initial data is nested, then you would need recursion.

Comment: I created a new function, actually the function is working for the items 1 to 6 but not for the others items. Some thing wrong with my recursion ? @AlexL yes the array is always ordered, could you show me a little example to realize this function without recursion ? thank you very much for your help

Comment: I posted an example / answer now - was a bit harder than I expected  (It would be easiest if your initial data was already nested and if not, it would be easier if you had parentID props on your flat data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. It was a bit harder than I initially thought, haha.

You do need to convert to a nested data structure and then to map that recursively to give the desired output:

Full demo below and here: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/pojXBWX

```js
function MyTable(props) {
  const initState = [
    {
      Level: 1,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118027222233,
      Name: "Name 1"
    },
    {
      Level: 2,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118636886633,
      Name: "Name 2"
    },
    {
      Level: 3,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118637048333,
      Name: "Name 3"
    },
    {
      Level: 4,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118637035433,
      Name: "Name 4"
    },
    {
      Level: 4,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118841127933,
      Name: "Name 5"
    },
    {
      Level: 4,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118841156833,
      Name: "Name 6"
    },
    {
      Level: 3,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118637046733,
      Name: "Name 9"
    },
    {
      Level: 4,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118744514633,
      Name: "Name 10"
    },
    {
      Level: 5,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118637033033,
      Name: "Name 11"
    },
    {
      Level: 5,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118637031033,
      Name: "Name 13"
    },
    {
      Level: 2,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 118636886633,
      Name: "Name 19"
    },
    {
      Level: 3,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118637048333,
      Name: "Name 20"
    },
    {
      Level: 3,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 118637048333,
      Name: "Name 21"
    },
    {
      Level: 2,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 128637048333,
      Name: "Name 22"
    },
    {
      Level: 3,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 138637048333,
      Name: "Name 23"
    },
    {
      Level: 1,
      "Type of activity": "Consolidated task",
      ID: 148637048333,
      Name: "Name 24"
    },
    {
      Level: 2,
      "Type of activity": "task",
      ID: 158637048333,
      Name: "Name 25"
    }
  ];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  const table = (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );

  let currPointer = null;
  const listOfPointers = [];
  const nestedArrs = state.reduce((aggArr, item) => {
    //console.log(listOfPointers)
    if (item.Level == 1) {
      aggArr.push(item);
    }
    else if (item.Level > currPointer.Level) {
      currPointer.children.push(item);
    }
    else if (item.Level <= currPointer.Level) {
      while (item.Level <= currPointer.Level) {
        listOfPointers.pop();
        currPointer = listOfPointers[listOfPointers.length - 1];
      }
      currPointer.children.push(item);
    }
    
    item.children = [];
    currPointer = item;
    listOfPointers.push(currPointer);

    return aggArr;
  }, []);

  //console.log(nestedArrs);

  const nestedDivs = (
    <div>
      {(function mapChildren(data) {
        return data.map((d, i) => {
          if (d["Type of activity"] != "task") {
            return (
              <div className={"level_" + d.Level}>
                <span>{d.Level + " : " + d.Name}</span>
                {mapChildren(d.children)}
              </div>
            );
          } else {
            return (
              <div className={"level_" + d.Level + " task"}>
                <span>{d.Level + " : " + d.Name}</span>
              </div>
            );
          }
        });
      })(nestedArrs)}
    </div>
  );
  //console.log(nestedDivs);

  return (
    <div>
      {table}
      {nestedDivs}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.level_1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.level_2 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.level_3 {
  background-color: green;
}
.level_4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.task {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexL ! Pass to nested data perfect. And the recursive function is very nice it was exactly what i’m looking for ! It’s one of my first javascript function and the recursion it’s little bit complex for me for the moment, but with your example it seems very clear ! Thanks again

Comment: Very happy to hear that my answer is clear  and that it is helpful  Recursion can get complex and messy quickly, but practice it a little and it can be very powerful! Good luck!